# React Native - Why does displaying components through iteration give the id prop as the last iteration number to all of the components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, backend

I receive some data from my server and then display it through iteration. Below is the code:

```
    function DisplayMenu(MenuText, defaultThis) {
        var menu = JSON.parse(MenuText);
        var CategoriesNum;
        CategoriesNum = menu.length;

        var i;
        var components = [];
        for (i = 1; i < CategoriesNum + 1; i++) {
            var temp = <View style={styles.category}>
                <Text style={styles.catTitle}>{menu[i - 1][i.toString()]["catTitle"]}</Text>
                <View style={styles.catItems}>
                    {generateItemC(menu, i, defaultThis)}
                </View>
            </View>;
            components[i] = temp;
        }
        return (
            <View>{components}</View>

        )
    }

    function generateItemC(menu, catNumber, defaultThis) {
        var ItemsNum;
        ItemsNum = menu[catNumber - 1][catNumber.toString()]["itemsarray"].length;

        var i;
        var thisi;
        var items = []
        for (i = 0; i < ItemsNum; i++) {
            thisi = i;
            var temp =
                <View style={styles.iteminfo}>

                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={"item_" + i} id={i} onPress={() => { defaultThis.setModalVisible1(true, catNumber, thisi ); }}>
                        <View style={styles.item}>

                            <View style={styles.itemImgPos} >
                                <Image style={styles.itemImg} source={require('./img/burger.jpg')}></Image>
                            </View>
                            <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>{menu[catNumber - 1][catNumber.toString()]["itemsarray"][i]["title"]}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.itemDesc}>{menu[catNumber - 1][catNumber.toString()]["itemsarray"][i]["desc"]}</Text>
                            <View style={styles.itemBottom}>
                                <Text style={styles.price}>{menu[catNumber - 1][catNumber.toString()]["itemsarray"][i]["price"]} • </Text>
                                <Icon name="clockcircleo" family="AntDesign" color="orange"></Icon>
                                <Text style={styles.colored} color="orange">15 min</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

                </View>;
            items[i] = temp
        }
        return (items)
    }
export default class Menu extends React.Component {
    getMenu() {
        var menu = JSON.parse(this.props.route.params['menu']);
        return menu;
    }
    state = {
        modalVisible1: false,
        modalVisible2: false,
        checked: 'first',
        isShowToast: false,
        isShowToastError: false,
        menuData: this.getMenu(),
        catNumber: 1,
        itemNumber: 1
    };

    setModalVisible1(visible, catNum, itemNum) {
        console.log(visible);
        console.log("catNum" + catNum);
        console.log("itemNum" + itemNum);
            this.setState({ catNumber: catNum, itemNumber: itemNum }, () => {
                this.setState({modalVisible1 : true})});
        }
...
```

For some reason the "Categories" actually do get the correct iteration number (id) when I console.log, but the "Items" do not. All items get the last iteration number. I need to pass the ID of the item to the onPress function in order to update the state to display the correct data on the modal.

I trigger the "DisplayMenu()" function like this in the render component:

```
{DisplayMenu(this.props.route.params['menu'], this)}
```

Now, I was wondering why this happens and how is it possible for me to pass on the item id to the onPress setModalVisible1 function? The Modal does show up but it has the wrong data. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Quick fix is remove `var thisi` and in the for loop do: `for (let i = 0; i < ItemsNum; i++) {` But it's better to use Array.prototyp.map (I will add an anser)

Comment: @HMR Thanks for the reply! I will check out Array.prototyp.map but how exactly do I integrate it with the way I want it outputted? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Array.prototype.map:

```
function generateItemC(menu, catNumber, defaultThis) {
  const ItemsNum =
    menu[catNumber - 1][catNumber.toString()]['itemsarray']
      .length;
  return ItemsNum.map((item, index) => (
    <View style={styles.iteminfo} key={index}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        key={'item_' + index}
        id={index}
        onPress={() => {
          defaultThis.setModalVisible1(
            true,
            catNumber,
            index
          );
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.item}>
          <View style={styles.itemImgPos}>
            <Image
              style={styles.itemImg}
              source={require('./img/burger.jpg')}
            ></Image>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.itemDesc}>{item.desc}</Text>
          <View style={styles.itemBottom}>
            <Text style={styles.price}>
              {item.price} •{' '}
            </Text>
            <Icon
              name="clockcircleo"
              family="AntDesign"
              color="orange"
            ></Icon>
            <Text style={styles.colored} color="orange">
              15 min
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
  ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help. Really appreciated! Now everything works fine.